# Only load one png file with class.getResourceAsStream(stringPath)

Tags: java, png, classloader, slick2d

I'am trying to finish my first Java Game with the slick2D library. 
I had it all working in eclipse but when i was about to make a jar file of it  i did realize that i had to use class loader to load my png - SpriteSheets.

But now to the problem. My ResourceLoader Class looks like this:

```
public static InputStream load(String path){
    InputStream input = MyResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
    if(input==null){
        input = MyResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+path);
    }
    return input;
}
```

My init-Method in the BasicGame class, where i try to load my png-files looks like this:

```
public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
    InputStream inputStream1 = MyResourceLoader.load("images/piratR.png");
    sprite1 = new SpriteSheet("",inputStream1,32,32);

    InputStream inputStream2 = MyResourceLoader.load("images/monkey.png");
    sprite2 = new SpriteSheet("",inputStream2,32,32);

    animation1 = new Animation(sprite1,200);
    animation2 = new Animation(sprite2,250);

}
```

And that works fine for loading the FIRST png-file(eg piratR.png), but whenever i try to load another file it just loads the first one again. So in this case sprite1 and sprite2 looks the same though there are different images.

I have been trying to get this straight for weeks, so if theres someone how could tell me what aim doing wrong or point me in the right direction i would be grateful.
//
Anders, Sweden

Comment: I would try swapping the order, because this really shouldn't happen. It is more likely the files are the same for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for you're reply Peter, but i have already tried to switch the "load-order", and if i do the switch, I get a diffrent looking animation, so the pictures are clearly different.